# Specific word/phrase/idiom for the following scenario

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, idioms, phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

I have a second cousin living at the end of my street, but we hardly meet. I plan to meet her soon and tell her to come out and go out for a walk.

Could anyone suggest a phrase, word, or an idiom for the following sentence I have written?

> I'll come to her home and take her out myself.

Comment: A common phrasal verb for this situation in British English is "_to pick someone up_". For example: "_I'll pick you up at 7:30._"

Comment: @Shoe I have no issue with your second suggestion. But I would be wary of suggesting "*to pick someone up*" out of context, as it commonly means to meet someone (new) at a bar, club, etc., and spend the night with them.

Comment: @trevord I know of no one who would think twice about using the expression "I'll pick you up at...", as it only has your stated social meaning in the right context. Picking up children at school is probably more typical than picking up strangers at a bar, for example.

Comment: @Jim Please re-read my comment: 1. I specifically said I had no issue with "*I'll pick you up at 7:30.*". 2. As regards the second one, I also specifically mentioned *context*, as you have done. I know nothing of the background or experience of OP, so was merely alerting him to possible misunderstanding. I don't disagree with anything you've said.

Comment: @TrevorD. Yes, it may be useful for the OP to be alerted to alternative senses of the verb _to pick up_. In fact, my Phrasal Verbs dictionary lists 16 different meanings, including the ones you and I refer to!

Comment: @Jim and Trevor.  I can see what Trevor is saying. I think the term 'pick-up someone' has become so much associated with prostitutes and bars, perhaps more so in the UK. I know I am always wary about arranging to 'pick someone up'. It is not that I think they would misunderstand my motive but it becomes a slightly embarrassing 'double-entendre'. There is a perfectly good alternative which I use, which is to say 'I shall collect you from your house at 7.30pm'.

Comment: That's funny. The only things that get collected at my house (in US) are taxes and garbage. (And the two are circuitously related, it seems.)

Comment: @Jim, Trevor and Shoe. But doesn't "I'll pick you up at 7.30pm" imply the person doing the picking has a car? And if two people live on the same street, why the need to pick or collect that person?

Comment: "I'll come to her home and take her out myself" sounds a bit like you're a mob hitman talking to your boss.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Depends on their mode of transportation. If person A is picking up B, I wouldn't expect B to drive (in agreement with your statement), but if they're walking, biking, taking the subway, etc. I'd say "I'll pick you up at 7:30" is still appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It potentially depends a bit on context, but in general I'd say something more along the lines of

> I'll be picking her up at her home.

or

> I'll be meeting her at her home.

*To take out* has many meanings, but when the object is a person, *take someone out*, it usually means either to kill them, or in the context of a particular event to prevent them from participating in said event. Though, with proper context and careful usage it can mean to take on a date.

Comment: ...As in "take her out of the running."

Comment: Right. Like "Tanya Harding had her bodyguard take out Nancy Kerrigan."

Answer (score 0):

I'll come by [her (*or* your) place] and take her (*or* you) out for a walk[, if she likes (*or* you like).]

Comment: In Britain we tend not to 'call by', or 'come by', though we do 'call in'. The last has a slightly different meaning. When you 'call in' or 'drop in' you do it with the express purpose of visiting the person(s). However we 'collect' them to take them somewhere. We could perhaps 'call by and collect them', that would not be an unknown usage here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll collect her from  her home, and take her out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are talking to a third person about your plans towards your cousin...
I like:

> "If the mountain won't come to Muhammad then Muhammad must go to the mountain."

It doesn't quite cover the "take her out" part but I feel it could be implicit.

Answer (score 0):

I'd feel a little like a dog if I were to be "taken for a walk."
I'd feel like a library book if I were "to be collected."
I'd think I'd prefer that someone "come" to my house (or that he "go" to it, and ask me to "walk with him,"